# android network state change issue with BroadCastReceiver

Tags: android, networking, broadcastreceiver

I have implemented app network state change with BroadcastReciver. It`s working well but one time my app icon was inactive despite of connected to network.The question is that what kinda reason android doesn't make me aware of that network is not available.Maybe when internet speed was so slow, phone was asleep. I wonder why it is working like that! If does anyone have any ideas it would be greatfull for me.

Comment: If you could post relevant part of your code and more details about your issue, there would be a much better chance of someone helping you.